# A comprehensive list of adware programs

Tags: adware

Is there a comprehensive list of adware programs like Babilon, Delta search, Conduit, Ask.com, etc? I could not manage to find something full-blown.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: http://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/threats.jsp

Comment: http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/malware/latest.aspx

Comment: Both of those programs are about as bad as adware itself. Are you sure those are good links? I'm not saying they aren't, I'm asking. I have no clue.

Comment: Yes, they are valid links that point to well-known (good or not) anti-malware companies that maintain threat lists. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no comprehensive list of adware - or any kind of software - because new ones come out daily, if not hourly.